# Defining custom operators for indexed objects

Tags: symbolic, packages, operators, indexed-variable

I have some symbolic indexed objects $A_i$, $B_{ij}$, $C_{ijk}$, $D_{ijkl}$, etc.

I want to define a symbolic differential operator $\partial_{xy}$ that acts on these indexed objects in the following way:
$$\partial_{xy} A_i = A_x \delta_{yi}$$
$$\partial_{xy} B_{ij} = B_{xj} \delta_{yi} + B_{ix} \delta_{yj}$$
$$\partial_{xy} C_{ijk} = C_{xjk} \delta_{yi} + C_{ixk} \delta_{yj} + C_{ijx} \delta_{yk}$$
$$\partial_{xy} (A_i B_{jk}) = A_x B_{jk} \delta_{yi} + A_i B_{xk} \delta_{yj} + A_i B_{jx} \delta_{yk}$$
and so on... Here $\delta_{ij}$ denotes the Kronecker delta function.

Can someone give me a hint how to define symbolic indexed objects in Mathematica and how create my custom operator $\partial_{xy}$? Maybe there are some packages that could be useful for solving my problem?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "custom operator" in this site? There are a few previous questions on this topic. You could then try to implement some of the suggested approaches, and then come back with a specific problem if they don't work.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use subscripted variables, use indexed variables.

Then it is not clear, if x and y are fixed or placeholders. To make it general, I assume x and y are placeholders and define an operator of the form:
op[{x,y},C[i,j,...]]

```
ClearAll[op]
op[{x_, y_}, x1_[x2__]] := Module[{ tmp = {x2}, i}, 
  Plus @@Table[x1 @@ ReplaceAt[tmp, _ -> x, i] KroneckerDelta[y,tmp[[i]]]
, {i, Length[tmp]}]]
```

With this we can write:

```
op[{x, y}, A[i]]
op[{x, y}, B[i, j]]
op[{x, y}, C[i, j, k]]
```

[image]

(Note KroneckerDelta rearranges the subscripts)

**Addendum**

For the case: A B we need an additional definition:

```
op[{x_, y_}, x1_[x2__]  x3__] := 
  op[{x, y}, x1[x2]]  x3 + x1[x2]  op[{x, y}, x3];
```

Now we can write:

```
op[{x, y}, A[i]  B[j, k]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine for a single object but unfortunately for a product of multiple indexed objects (e.g. $A_i B_{jk}$ - the last example in my question) the result is incorrect.

Comment: For this we need an additional definition. See my addendum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! I apologize for a lot of questions - but what about more general expressions like $\partial_{xy} (A_{i} B_{jk} C_{lmn})$, $\partial_{xy} (A_{i} B_{jk} C_{lmn} D_{opqr})$, etc.? Your code now works for one and two indexed objects but not for three or more

Comment: I probably didn't fully formulate my problem: I actually need the operator $\partial_{xy}$ to act on abstract sums involving these indexed objects. For example $\partial_{xy}\sum_i(A_iA_i)=\sum_i(2A_xA_i\delta_{iy})=2A_xA_y$ or $\partial_{xy}\sum_i(A_iB_{ij})=\sum_i(A_x\delta_{iy}B_{ij}+A_iB_{xj}\delta_{iy}+A_i B_{ix}\delta_{jy})=A_xB_{yj}+A_yB_{xj}+\sum_iA_iB_{ix}\delta_{jy}$